# How can I plot this step function using matlab?

Tags: matlab

How do you plot this step function in matlab without using 'step'?
x(t)=t[u(t)-u(t-3)]

I tried with this:

```
t=-10:1:10;
h=t*(heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-3));
stem(t,h)
grid on;
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
```

But the following error appeared: "Error using  * 
Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the number of rows in the second matrix. To perform elementwise multiplication, use '.*'."

Comment: Use the element-wise multiplication `.*` instead of the matrix multiplication `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t=-10:0.01:10;
f = double(t >= 0 & t < 3);
plot(t, f)
grid on
```

[image]